# This query throws an error in one server and in another it doesn't

Tags: mysql

I was migrating an old app to a new hosting got a super weird error that looks like this.

This throws error in PHP MySQLi (Unknown column 't0.colx' in 'order clause'):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT colx, ...
    FROM ...
) AS t0
ORDER BY t0.colx
```

This passes without problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT colx, ...
    FROM ...
) AS t0
ORDER BY colx
```

Removing the t0 shows no error whatsoever.
In the old server I was using both works.

Anyone can point me out if I'm doing something wrong?

EDIT:
just to clarify, the error in being thrown by PHP's Mysqli not Mysql iself I think, if I copy paste the sql into phpmyadmin it throws no error and returns the data correctly. The error message I'm getting from mysqli object in mysqli->error property after I check if the mysqli->execute() returns false.

- Versions:
  PHP Version 5.5.38
  Mysql 5.7.39
- Removing "AS" didnt work.

The column named for "ORDER BY" its selected this way, maybe thats throwing the error? but on older hosting no error is shown.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
   SELECT
   ...
   if(numDoc IS NOT NULL, numDoc, CAST(numDocEx AS UNSIGNED)) AS numDoc,
   ...
) t0
ORDER BY t0.numDoc
```

Comment: I guess the new engine refuse you to create an  aliace on a temp table that got created inside the brackets. Just from curiosity remove `AS`...

Comment: What is a version of mysql server that is giving you a hard time?

Comment: I can't see any reason why it would fail in any version of MySQL.

Comment: I tried it in every version of MySQL at db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pi2RGpfd4uvE3h2PNaNFm4/0 and they all worked. Please post a [mre].

Comment: thanks for your responses Ill post everything you asked in a min.

Comment: I think that MySQL server receives not your query but its interpretation made by your program. Enable General log and look what SQL text is received by MySQL really, compare it with original one..

Comment: Ill google how to do that and Ill enable it.